# when does shmget() returns zero shmid?

Tags: linux, sysv-ipc

I am running simple test program which is using SYSV shared memory. I found that sometime shmget() is returning the zero shmid, if requested shared memory segment is already exist. can anybody explain in which scenario shmaget() returns zero shmid ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend you search for `man shmaget` using a search engine of your choice. Or you do it on your system, provided the respective man pages are installed.

Comment: I have already gone through man page of shmget. Its says that "On success, a valid shared memory identifier is returned.  On errir, -1 is returned" . My concern is that is zero is valid shmid ? and in which scenario shmget() return zero.

Comment: If that's what the man page says I think you should rely on it. `-1` is an error code, and otherwise it's an valid shared memory ID (including `0`). That's pretty common for these types of functions. Where's the problem? It's simply an ID, not an address or so. And most probably the IDs just increment.

Comment: It means that i am checking  return value of shmget() wrongly. I am checking for if (0 < shmget(key, size, flags)  then success. zero should be treated as valid id. I got this doubt because it is very rare  that shmget() returning zero.  Thank you very for your valuable time .